# Editing of a saved LibreOffice writer document in MS WordPad

Tags: libreoffice, file-format, conversion

I am new to Libre Office.  I have a problem with the format in which to save a office document (when comparing to Microsoft office)

I have set up my Libre office writer doc (call it a master document) But as soon as I save the doc (i SAVE IT IN ODT FORMAT) it change the layout and then open it as a wordpad document - which do not have all the functions of the office writer.

I have to edit a lot of documents for my work, add pics etc.

Please help. what do I do wrong?  I need the document in the same format it was (office writer) when I re-open it again for editing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are trying to open a Libreoffice document is MS WordPad in windows for this answer.

[MS WordPad natively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) reads RTF but can open Word 6-2003 .doc format.

Thus you will need to use Libreoffice SaveAs function and change the output type to either RTF or Microsoft Word 6 - 2003

[image]

Obviously, converting from one file format to another file format can lose some formatting capabilities.  Thus you will need to experiment:

- Try to keep your Libreoffice/MS WordPad documents simple.  A good guide would be - if MS Wordpad cant do a particular function or capability, then dont do the capability in Libreoffice.
- When writing in Libreoffice, use the fonts available in MS WordPad as a guide- or at least similar sounding names.  Remember to use the TrueType fonts in the `msttcorefonts` package.